# oracle sql error:distinct case

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select a distinct column from an oracle database,my code is:

```
select ID,distinct case when DM='ST1B' then MC else DM end from D_DZDY
```

but,it does not work.If i remove 'distinct',it works:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPcjN.png)

Anybody can help me with this problem?thanks a lot! :D

Comment: You are using `DISTINCT` with wrong syntax. Please give some dummy data and what is your expected results.

Comment: Are you looking for `select distinct ID,case when DM='ST1B' then MC else DM end from D_DZDY;`?

Comment: What ID would you expect to see in case you have 10 rows with the same CASE value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is `select distinct`.  There is no `distinct` function or operator on a single column.

Perhaps you intend:

```
select distinct ID, (case when DM = 'ST1B' then MC else DM end)
from D_DZDY;
```

This will return distinct pairs of `id` and the `case` expression.

Comment: No need for brackets around CASE

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . I always put `case` in parentheses.  I find it much easier to see where the `case` ends, particularly when they are nested

Comment: The comment is for the OP/readers. Since this is another change from the OP code, It was important to to clarify that this is a cosmetic change only.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT OPERATE ON ROW, YOU SHOULD USE THIS SYNTAX :

```
select distinct  ID,(case when DM='ST1B' then MC else DM end) from D_DZDY
```

IF YOU JUST WANT DEFERMENT VALUES OF THE CASE STATEMENT YOU COULD USE THIS

```
select distinct  (case when DM='ST1B' then MC else DM end) from D_DZDY
```

Comment: No need for brackets around CASE

Comment: No need to SCREAM AT US. Please fix your caps-lock key, it's broken